# How to refresh children on reopening node in JsTree?

Tags: jquery, jstree

Im using ajax loading for children nodes in JQuery JsTree plugin. I need to refresh all children nodes if I  reopen loaded node in web browser.

Comment: Do you mean that you need to make another ajax call?

Comment: I need remove children on closing node, and make ajax call on opening

Comment: What about refresh on double click or so?

Comment: No. Double click isn't obliviously for user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this where on close new class is added to the node that causes node to be refreshed on open. If the class is present. So you can remove the on close_node part and add your own class name for nodes that needs to be refreshed on open

```
$(function () {
    var tree_id="#jstree"
    var ajax_again="to-be-refreshed";

    $(tree_id).bind("open_node.jstree close_node.jstree", function (e,data) {
        var currentNode = data.args[0];
        if(e.type === "close_node") {
            currentNode.addClass(ajax_again);
        }   
        if(e.type === "open_node") {
            if (currentNode.hasClass(ajax_again)) { 
                var tree = $.jstree._reference(tree_id);
                tree.refresh(currentNode);
            }  
        }
    })  .jstree({
```

or you can use simplified version when all nodes are refresh on open

```
$(function () {
    var tree_id="#jstree"

    $(tree_id).bind("open_node.jstree close_node.jstree", function (e,data) {
        var currentNode = data.args[0];
        if(e.type === "open_node") {
            var tree = $.jstree._reference(tree_id);
            tree.refresh(currentNode);
        }
    })  .jstree({
```

Answer (score 2):

I could not find a jstree API to do this, so I looked in the source code.

If you use `children: true`, it will use click-to-load the first time it opens. It checks `node.state.loaded` to know whether or not to load it the first time.

So this event handler worked well for me:

```
        .on('after_close.jstree', function (event, data) {
            // Flag it to be reloaded on reopen:
            data.node.state.loaded = false;
        });
```

The `after_close.jstree` event happens when the close animation completes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

None of above codes worked for me. Below is my code that it works:

```
$('.tree-container').on('close_node.jstree', function (event, data) {
    var tree = $.jstree.reference('.tree-container');
    tree.refresh(data.node);
});
```

Comment: That's basically because you use a new version of jstree. There was an API change some time ago.